# 500 internal server error in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, internal-server-error

I am using thethe-image-slider plugin in wordpress to display the slider and this plugin is making use of timthumb script to resize the images.But on my live server this I am getting 500 internal server error when trying to access this script.

Can someone please help me with the cause of this problem?

Comment: Do you have access to the web server error logs?

Comment: This can have a lot of reasons - most likely, the script's memory limit. The error log would give definite information, but trying to raise the memory limit would probably be a good idea. You may need to the server's admin to do that though

Comment: But the same script is running when placing it on the root folder.Problem is only with plugins folder

Comment: Hmm, that's really odd. The quickest way to find out what the problem is would be talking to the server admin and ask them what the error logs say.